# understanding python requests session parameters

Tags: python, twitter

I am trying to experiment with twitter api and I am using tweepy api to understand an api design... For this particular argument lets, take a look at this api https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/users/show

An example rest request looks like https://api.twitter.com/1.1/users/show.json?screen_name=rsarver

So, I don't want to build a  url string..

I am trying to dig deep into https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/blob/master/tweepy/binder.py code..

To be more specific.

```
s = requests.Session()
```

and then `build_parameters()` function where they are setting the parameters...

In the code, they never explicitly builds the url

In the `execute_code()`,
if i do `print full_url` it is simply `( https://api.twitter.com/1.1/users/show.json)`

I am guessing in build_parameters, self.session.params where the variable is set and then line 156 is where all the action happens ??

```
resp = self.session.request(self.method, full_url,
                                                data=self.post_data, timeout=self.api.timeout,
                                                auth=auth, proxies=self.api.proxy)
```

But for debugging purposes, I really want to know what "string url" is being executed. How do I get that "string"? Or maybe I havent fully understand the code.

Long story short.

I want to make request to twitter api but I dont want to "build" string...rather use this sessions parameter to handle it but at the same time, eventually I want to print the string which is being "requested" ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The full url you're looking for is in the response object you get back from the request:

```
resp = self.session.request(self.method, full_url,
                                                data=self.post_data, timeout=self.api.timeout,
                                                auth=auth, proxies=self.api.proxy)
print resp.url # This is the url you want
```

I can't tell if this is actually useful to you or not. Are you trying to get that url while still using tweepy (and without changing tweepy)? Or are you just looking at tweepy to understand how to interact with Twitter's API?

Answer (score 0):

With simple ctrl-F I was able to find where `full_url` is constructed, in line 113 and 114

```
url = self.api_root + self.path
full_url = 'https://' + self.host + url
```

Is this what you are looking for?
Using the same method you can search where `self.api_root` and `self.path` are defined.

Comment: Its not the full url.. It is the base url.. and then the arguments (parameters) are set in build_parameters.. and is set in self.session.params.

Comment: Are you wanting to know where 'users/show.json' is being added to the url? It is passed as an argument to bind_api method. If you look at api.py lines 254-262, 'users/show.json' is passed as the 'path' parameter to bind_api(), and line 113 and line 114 is where path gets used.